# COM port forwarding software

Tags: redirection, serial-port

I need to find software to redirect COM port from PC with device to remote server (over ethernet). But first: connection must be initialized by client to server (from PC with device), and second: client device must persists COM port number on server (f.e. client must get COM9 each time he connects).

Does anyone know any kinds of software offering this capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

[A quick Google search](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=com+port+to+ethernet+software) [showed quite a few](http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/utilities-tools/com-port-redirector.html) [options that you](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hw_vsp/index_en.html) [can give a try.](http://www.taltech.com/tcpcom)

Though depending on what more specifics you are trying to do, you might need to search around more or develop your own if things don't integrate the way you'd like.

Hope that can point you in good direction.